# Get the current domain name in django

Tags: python, django

I want to get the current domain name in Django.Earlier I got this using

```
site_name = RequestSite(request).domain
```

But Now I want to get the domain name without request parameter . This is so because I am using a twitter package in my project and the function in which i want to use have no request parameter thus i can't use the above mentioned code there.

So is there in way of getting current domain without request parameter.
I ahve also used 'get_current_site' but it always gives .com domain name.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the .com domain name?

Comment: Because I am working on multisite project, and when any user register through twitter via other then .com , Then it redirect the user to .com always . But I want that He redirected to that domain from where he registers.

Comment: Which Twitter package are you using, what function are you calling? Can you provide a more complete source example?

Comment: sorry for late reply , but I have found the solutions . I have just edited the package function (package name -- django-socialregistration) . By the way thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0):

The Site.object.get_current gives you the "default" site (look [how it's implemented](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sites/models.py#L28)). Without access to the Request object, you have to find another way to lookup or contruct your domain.